# Motorcycle Race Results SQL queries to select and insert values or records

Tags: sql

I have an SQL table, `PointsClass`.

This table is used to upload motorcycle race results per competition class.
Fields in table:

1. IDNumber [Competitor IDNumber, primary key]
2. EventName [Race Name]
3. Class [Competition Class entered i.e. OR1, OR2, Ladies]
4. Position [Race Results class position i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 etc]
5. Classpoints [Points awarded depending on race position finish]

A competitor can enter all or some of their races, **but**, as it is a competition series, the competitor upon entering any race and Class, must be awarded points for not only the race they entered, but also be awarded penalty points for the races they did not enter (use 10 penalty points as the example for races this competitor did not enter).

If 3 races have already taken place and the competitor enters the 4th race in class "OR1", then the code must check if the competitor has entered the 3 previous races in the "OR1" class. If not, then we must "create" the `competitorrecord` in the previous 3 races and award 10 penalty points per race (for not competing in that 3 races) and also in the same class "OR1" the competitor entered in the 4th race. This will be the "Position" or results field.

**CATCH** - the code must not only award the 10 penalty points, but first check **how many entries per race** there was in the OR1 class and add the penalty points to that total. E.g., Race 1 had 30 entries in the "OR1" class and Race 2 had 40 entries in the "OR1" class and Race 3 had 50 entries in the "OR1" class. This means the competitor penalty will be for race 1 - 30 + 10, Race 2 - 40 + 10 and race 3 - 50 + 10

Code I have to "count" entries per class per event;

```
SELECT   EventName, Class, Count(Class)  AS CountofClass
FROM     PointsClass
GROUP BY Class, EventName
ORDER BY EventName
```

Comment: Missing some information, I think. If your Competitor Id number is your PK, any competitor can only ever participate in one race.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried, some code that doesn't work?

Comment: Other detail: I would not create those "not entered" records, but calculate them when needed. Otherwise yuo will have a problem determining the number of actual entries per race, as you create entry records for competitors that did not actually enter (if race 5 has 60 competitors, every race before that will also have had 60!). That _would_ make calculating your penalty points easier, but I don't think it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for replying and yes you're correct. If I add new records my entries will not be accurate. Could I still add records, but add a marker field which indicates "non entries" and can be excluded when actual entries are calculated.

Comment: Oerkelens,I would love to show what is not working, however, what I have is standard single code for importing the results, another for counting the number of entries "as above", but I am unable or rather way to incompetent to even try put my requirement in code.

Comment: Maybe i'm doing this all wrong, what do you advise; I have 1 table to which the results is uploaded. Every record [competitor result] for each and every race is appended to this table as and when the import is done. So in the end i'm sitting with 1 table with all the events and results. Is this wise? The table has a separate PK which is not part of the fields above.

Comment: I would suggest you do not try to store indirect data in your table :) So if you want to calculate each Competitor's total score over all events, calculate it when you retrieve it :)

Comment: Sound good oerkelens, PLSE point me to a starting point for this [coding wise]. I'll study and try through trial and error